# How can I optimize a numpy code of averaging data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization

I'm currently trying to optimize a function in Python.

Is there a clever use of Numpy to get result in less time ?

I have data of shape (30000,18000) and a window_size of 2.

```
import time
import numpy as np
def denoise(data, window_size, axis=0):
    output = np.zeros((data.shape[axis], data.shape[axis+1] // window_size))
    i = 0
    for k in range(0, data.shape[axis + 1] - window_size, window_size):
        output[:,i] = np.sum(data[:,k:k+window_size],axis=axis+1)/window_size
        i = i+1
    return output

data = np.random.random((30000,18000))
start = time.time()
output = denoise(data,2)
print(f'Elapsed time {time.time()-start} s')
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do, and give a non-random, well crafted  [mre] that demonstrates the logic (rather than a huge random one).

Comment: Are you trying to perform a rolling average over the second axis? There are built-in functions for that, either in NumPy or SciPy.

Comment: It looks like you're doing a pooling operation. It can be useful to use a library like scikit-image has [block reduce](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce)

Comment: Why do you include the `data.shape[axis + 1] - window_size` that would leave off the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a small but significant improvement to your current method.

```
n = data.shape[1]
output = sum( data[:, k:n:window_size] for k in range(window_size) )/window_size
return output
```

That removes the need for iterating over each element, and instead using numpy's slice routine. The time goes from 25s to less than 2s for me.

**Note the axis argument doesn't work in your original example.**

Comment: If I compare both inputs with np.allclose(), there are not the same.

Comment: @montardon I asked about that in the comments. Why do you leave the last column off? If you want it to be the same you can set the last column of the output to be zero, but I suspect your original example is broken.

Comment: I tested the block reduce of skimage. It is just slighly slower than your solution.

Comment: I suppose there are some trade-offs for the flexibility that block_reduce offers. I find it impressive with numpy/python. data[:, k:n:window_size] essentially allocates a new array populated with the data, and doing that k times is faster than iterating over the array.